# Is TP4056 protection absolutely necessary?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, lipo, over-discharge

My battery has over-charge, over-discharge, and over-current detection properties.

Do I need to use the famous protection circuit as an extra? What are the advantages or disadvantages of this situation?

Do FS8205 and dw01a have any other features that I am not aware of?

[image]

Comment: TP4056 is a battery charger IC and doesn't have almost any inherent protection. It ensures that the battery is charged with constant current first, then with constant voltage afterwards. It's a "quasi-smart" *(or smart enough, if you like)* battery charger IC, nothing more.

Comment: I know :) Bu My question is different. Please look picture.

Even if my battery provides the over current,over charge and over discharge specifications, do I need to use the famous protection circuit (include FS8205,DW01A) as an extra? @RohatKılıç

Comment: Some battery packs do have the overcharge/overdischarge/thermal protection circuit which consists of at least two MOSFETs and a controller IC. So if your battery pack has some protection specifications then this means that it already has the "famous circuit" in the package. So no, you don't need anything extra. By the way, by looking at the title and the content I understood that you are talking about TP4056 as a famous protection circuit. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks a lot :)